# deleting and renaming files

Tags: svn, git, revision

When working with a checked-out copy of an SVN or Git project, I often delete or rename files without using the appropriate `git mv`, `svn rename`, `git rm`, or `svn delete` commands, so these changes are not appropriately reflected when I commit my version back to the repository. Is there a workaround to fix this after the fact, besides being more careful on my end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Git, have a look at [`git add -A`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html#_options). This will add everything which is new or changed, as well as removing files which are not there anymore. It might also add files you don't really want to add, though, so be careful here.
As git does not track renames explicitly, this should be enough (together with a `git commit`).

For Subversion, you could do something like [`svn add --force .`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) followed by a `svn commit` to do the equivalent, but this will not track renames/moves properly. I think it is not trivial to find out which files were renamed (and maybe changed as well) and which were simply added/removed.

Comment: Unfortunate that it will add unwanted files but I suppose git can't be that smart (yet).

Comment: If you have some pattern which matches these unwanted files, put them in `.gitignore` (or `.git/info/exclude`), and they won't be added automatically.

Answer (score 2):

With git, `git mv` is just a convenient alias and is equivalent to moving a file and doing a `git rm` on the old file. If you omit using this, the result is you deleted the original file, which git will notice, and added a new file, which git will ignore because you haven't called `git add`. `git rm` is similar.

This is one of the downsides of git since it does not force you to commit every change in your repository as other version control systems do. However, it can be easily managed with the `git status` command and careful use of .gitignore files. So long as you keep your tree clean, or appropriately ignored, you can tell at a quick glance whether you have any untracked files that you missed.

As far as fixing this after the fact, just stage and commit the appropriate changes, which in this case will be untracked files.

Answer (score 1):

For git, once you removed a file, use:

```
git rm --cached myfile
```

Comment: Do I have to go find which ones I deleted and manually do this for each file?

Comment: There must be a smart way to do all in one go, git is very powerful, but I don't know it.

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I was hoping for. Otherwise I could also do `git rm` on the files I deleted as well (even if the files aren't there).

Answer (score 1):

In git if you have deleted files, you can use `git commit -a` and the commit will reflect the deletes without having to do a `git rm`

Gui tools like TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit are smart about such things and you generally don't have to do explicit delete and renames when using such tools.

Comment: thanks -- I do use `git commit -a` but that did not seem to remove my old files...